# Integration of $x^n e^{-x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been trying solve this, and even though I feel I'm really close to the answer- I'm quite unsure of the actual answer.

The question is a definite integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {e^x}\,dx$$

So, I'm integrating it by parts, and going by the LAITE principle, I get:

$$I_n = \frac {-x^n} {e^x} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {n x^{n-1}} {e^x}\,dx$$

The value inside the integral is $nI_{n-1}$, so all I'm left is to get the limit of the first term as x ranges from 0 to infinity.

I know $n!$ = $\sum\frac {x^n} {e^x}$ .

Somehow, I'm not exactly sure why I feel like the limit of the first term would go to zero (or n!), given that formula, but I'm not exactly sure how to substitute the n! formula for $e^x$. How do I proceed from here?

The options are

- $n! -nI_{n-1} $
- $ n! + nI_{n-1}$
- $ nI_{n-1}$
- none of these

Comment: hint : limit of the first part is zero

Comment: I don't know understand why exactly

Comment: Do you know the Gamma function ?

Comment: Is it because x^n increases much more slowly than e*x as x increases?

Comment: No i don't :/ I'll google it though

Comment: The Gamma function $\Gamma$ can be defined on $]0,+\infty[$ by : 

$$ \forall x \in ]0,+\infty[, \; \Gamma(x) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t} \, dt. $$

By integration by parts, it follows that : $\displaystyle \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; \Gamma(n+1) = n!$. However, the idea is to integrate by parts.

Comment: use hospital $$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{e^x}=0\\$$$$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^x}=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2x}{e^x}=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{e^x}=0\\$$ $$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x}=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{e^x}=...=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{e^x}=0\\$$

Comment: ohh, okay. That implies the entire integration would be n!. i.e $I_{n-1}$ is (n-1)!, which would mean the first part of my integration equates to zero. I don't exactly understand why that would be though.

Comment: OHHH. thanks darya! It makes sense now.

Comment: No I don't think you understand, because none of the others have pointed out that your expression for $I_n$ is undefined.

Comment: @user21820 How so?

Comment: @Autolatry You didn't write $I_n = \dots$ to start with, at least that's the only thing I see. And that's pretty minor, because it's clear what you meant from context.

Comment: @Autolatry: The asker wrote "$I_n = ...$" in which $x$ was simply not defined. This kind of foundational issue is the reason why it is difficult for many students to learn math.

Comment: Well, you're correct of course but surely for the purposes of context with regard to the OP's question, we all knew what he was driving at?

Comment: @Autolatry: It wasn't clear at all when I read it earlier since he said "**limit** of the first term" and so I thought he was taking limits, which was 'confirmed' when he said "feel like the limit of the first term would go to zero (or n!)". Hence my comment above. In any case, I consider my comment to be still accurate, even if it was not so relevant to the question here.

Comment: @user21820 Your point is certainly non-trivial and appropriate. Many thanks.

Comment: Hem, you should double check your formula $n!$ = $\sum\frac {x^n} {e^x}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By parts,
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty x^ne^{-x}\,dx=-x^ne^{-x}\Big|_{x=0}^\infty+n\int_{x=0}^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx.$$
The first term vanishes so that
$$I_n=nI_{n-1}.$$

As the base case is
$$I_0=\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=-e^{-x}\Big|_{x=0}^\infty=1,$$
we get the superb formula
$$I_n=n!$$

---

Note that as $e^x$ contains all powers of $x$,

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\ge\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},$$
and $$0\le x^ne^{-x}\le\frac1{(n+1)!x},$$allowing the limit at $\infty$ to cancel.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote for $I_n$ makes no sense because $x$ is undefined. The integration by parts does not give that. If you have an indefinite integral, it gives an indefinite integral. If you have a definite integral, then you need to evaluate the corresponding indefinite integral over the given interval. Specifically, $\int \frac {x^n} {e^x}\,dx = -\frac{x^n}{e^x} + \int \frac {nx^{n-1}} {e^x}\,dx$ and hence $\int_0^\infty \frac {x^n} {e^x}\,dx = [ -\frac{x^n}{e^x} ]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty \frac {nx^{n-1}} {e^x}\,dx$.

To see why $\frac{x^n}{e^x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, one could use L-Hopital, but a simpler reason is that $\frac{x}{e^x} \le \frac{x}{1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2} \to 0$, and the limit of a finite product is the product of the limits if they exist.

Also, as *Yves Daoust* pointed out in the comments, your statement about $n!$ is wrong. (Sorry I didn't look at it earlier.) Firstly, never write $\sum$ just like that unless you know absolutely what you are doing. Always include the (integer) variable that you are summing over, and the lower and upper limits. For example, $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{C}$. Note that in this statement $n$ is meaningless outside the summation, because it is being used as the counter variable in the summation! So it would be automatically meaningless to 'manipulate' it into $\color{red}{ e^x = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n }$, because $n$ here would be undefined. Furthermore, there is no way to define $n$ to make it true, because for instance $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ would be infinite if $x = 1$.